# How to crawl links with scrapy only from specific category, and ignore links on product page?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I want to crawl products from a category but I don't want the spider to follow the links found on the product page itself (related products are from the same brand but of different type - eg. the product I want is a perfume and it has as a related product a lipstick) .

The url for the category is `site.com/category_name/` and the product url is `site.com/brand_name/product-name-here/`. How should I define the crawling rules?

Comment: So have you tried to solve this yourself and ran into a problem?  Can you show some code?

Comment: I'm just starting with scrapy, have 0 experience with python and i'm scrambling to get things started. I posted the question mainly to know the right path i should take because i don't have much time to get it to work. I'm sure it's pretty basic what i want to do, but i need some guidance to get me started

Answer (score 0):

You can use rules to define this kind of behavior.

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*site.com/category_pattern.*',)),
callback='your_callback', follow=False)
```

This will crawl category pages with your callback, that will follow links to product pages and nothing from there. You just need some pattern for identifying category part of the url.